# Definition of Higgs bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I currently try to deal with the definition of a Higgs bundle:

The definition is: $(E, \varphi)$ is called a Higgs bundle, if

$E$ is a holomorphic vector bundle and

$\varphi$ is a holomorphic 1-form with values in $End(E)$, s.t. $\varphi \wedge \varphi=0$

Now I am not sure what holomorphic 1-form with values in $End(E)$. Is it a section of $T^{*}M \otimes End(E)$? Since the definition of a 1-form in general is that it is a section in $T^{*}M$.

Also, I am reading a paper where it says

'Because $\varphi$ takes values in the adjoint
representation, we can think of it locally as an $n \times n$ matrix of holomorphic one-forms –
which we can take to act on the fiber of $E$.'

I don't understand what 'takes values in the adjoint
representation' means here and how it is related to the above definition.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, the standard definition (like the one in the Wikipedia article and the linked AMS Notices article) is sloppy, although, one can get used to it.

1. A holomorphic 1-form $\phi$ (on a complex manifold $M$) with coefficients in a holomorphic vector bundle $V\to M$ is a **holomorphic** section of the vector   bundle $T^{(1,0)*}M \otimes V$. (By abusing the terminology, one identifies $T^{(1,0)*}_xM$ and $T^*_xM$.)

Assuming that $M$ is $m$-dimensional and $V=End(E)$, the endomorphism bundle of a holomorphic vector bundle $E\to M$ which has finite rank $n$, one can write $\phi$ (in local holomorphic coordinates) as 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m A_j(z) dz^j,  
$$ 
where each $A_j$ is a holomorphic map $U\to Mat_{n\times n}({\mathbb C})=End({\mathbb C}^n)$, and $U\subset {\mathbb C}^m$ is a suitable open subset. This is what it means for $\phi$ to be a matrix-valued holomorphic 1-form or a matrix of holomorphic 1-forms.

The words *adjoint representation* are irrelevant here.

2. The adjoint representation becomes important when you want to make sense  of the equation $\phi\wedge \phi=0$. If $\phi$ were a scalar-valued  1-form, then the wedge product would be the anti-symmetrization of the tensor product of $(1,0)$-forms. The question is how to deal with a tensor-field which is a section of  $T^{(1,0)*}M \otimes E$. What is used in the context of Higgs fields is the **Lie bracket** on $End({\mathbb C}^n)$:
   $$
   [a,b]= ab-ba, a, b\in End({\mathbb C}^n). 
   $$
   The latter is the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ of $GL_n({\mathbb C})$ and the **adjoint representation** of this Lie algebra is the representation given by the Lie bracket:
   $$
   a\mapsto [a, \cdot], a\in  {\mathfrak g}. 
   $$
   The expression $\phi\wedge \phi$ is then the usual wedge-product on $T^{(1,0)*}M$ and the Lie bracket of the (matrix-valued) coefficients. In local coordinates, 
   $$
   A(z)dz^i \wedge B(z) dz^j= [A(z), B(z)]dz^i \wedge dz^j.
   $$
   In other words, the equation $\phi\wedge \phi=0$ simply means that the matrices  $A_i(z), A_j(z)$ commute (for all $z$ and all $i, j$):
   $$
   [A_i(z), A_j(z)]= 0, 1\le i< j\le m, z\in U.  
   $$
   If $M$ is a Riemann surface then this condition is satisfies automatically. 
   (Each matrix, of course, commutes with itself.)

Thus, the slang *with coefficients in the adjoint representation* means the above rule for defining the wedge product of sections of $T^{(1,0)*}M \otimes End(E)$.

Comment: Hey, thanks already for the answer. I think I understand it, but I'm not sure what you mean by $T^{(1,0)}^{*}M$ (more specifically by the $(1,0)$. The one forms of type $f \ dz$?

Comment: @User1: This is the holomorphic cotangent bundle. You can find definitions in any textbook discussing complex geometry, for instance, Griffiths and Harris. Or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936273/definition-of-complex-differential-forms-of-bidegree-p-q?rq=1)

Comment: Another question: If $E$ is a $G$ bundle for some group $G$, is $\varphi$ then defined to be a holomorhpic section in $G \otimes T^{*}M$?

Comment: What would the notation $G\otimes T^*M$ mean? I also suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: Hey, I did here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511084/higgs-bundle-with-structure-group-vector-bundle